# Search not showing results from 'Person or Group' field

Tags: 2010, search-results, people-search, crawled-property

I have an issue returning results from a field called 'Name' of type 'Person or Group' showing Name (with presence).  I'd like to be able to search for the first or last name that appears when displaying the field this way.

In CA, do i need to create a new managed property called 'Name' and Add a Mapping (Combined name?)?

If someone could step-by-step the process i'd be eternally grateful, thank you!

Comment: I think,you need to create a separate a  search vertical - people - and provide the  sps3://ur_HTTP_URL in the content source.  also another option is that, you can create a managed property for this  person or group field and add it inside a  refinement web part. Also, did you re-index the  document library or splist once? you can do this once and make the option for allow this column shown in search results to True.

Answer (score 1):

I think,you need to create a separate a search vertical - people - and provide the **sps3://ur_HTTP_URL** in the content source.

Also another option is that, you can create a managed property for this person or group field and add it inside a refinement web part.

central admin-contentsource-sps3:
  [image: sps3-people-search]

Did you re-index the document library or splist once? you can do this once and make the option for allow this column shown in search results to True.

[image: adv-settings-doclib]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  Nothing is every straight-forward in SP :) I have added an index but can't find where to allow column to be searchable........................(cannot line break here it keeps submitting instead).  How would i create a managed property?  I can call it Name? and what would it be mapped to?  Thank you!

Comment: i have updated my answer, see above. hope you get the info. and based on this, you can proceed. also, go through the below blog series  to understand search etc : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/06/19/stage-14-configure-refiners-for-faceted-navigation/

Comment: Person Fields have NOTHING to do with the User Profiles crawled through sps3://

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new column in SharePoint 2010 and you want to be able to search for the content of the column, you have to create a Managed Property based on the Crawled Property. This means that you have to perform a crawl before and a Full Crawl after you have created the Property.

Create a new Managed property and map it to the "ows_ColumnName" that you added to your list. Then you will be able to query and retrieve the items that contain the values in your column.

I have created a video series for SharePoint 2013/2016 (the process is similar in 2010) on the topic of Managed Properties on YouTube. You can get there from here: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2017/07/19/search-based-site-directory-part-3/